# My "custom model data" textures didn't work with my own file

Tags: java, minecraft

This is my wooden_sword.json, the item/gold is a .png file I added. And it didn't work, only show the error purple/black texture.

```
{
  "parent": "item/handheld",
  "textures": {
    "layer0": "item/wooden_sword"
  },
  
  "overrides":[
  {"predicate": {"custom_model_data":1}, "model":"item/iron_ingot"},
  {"predicate": {"custom_model_data":2}, "model":"item/gold"}
  ]
}
```

The item/iron_ingot is the original file of the pack, and work correctly. I think there are some problems of loading the texture I added

Answer (score 1):

I finished it. All I have to do is adding a .json file named [texture name].json in the models file.

```
{
    "parent": "item/generated",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "item/[texture name]"
    }
}
```

After this, it showed the texture of my own files.